# Type resolution with higher kinded types and implicits

Tags: scala, scalaz

I am trying to write a Value Class to add functionality to anything that implements `Seq[_]` and allow it to make batch calls that return a `Future[_]` (specifically, I am using it to make batch REST calls).

```
final class BatchedList[A, C[X] <: Seq[X]](val targetList: C[A]) extends AnyVal {

  def batchRequests[B](batchSize: Int)(runner: Seq[A] => Seq[Future[Either[Result, B]]])
    (implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[C[A], Either[Result, B], C[Either[Result, B]]]): Future[Either[Result, C[B]]] = {
      targetList.grouped(batchSize).foldLeft(Future.successful(bf(targetList))) { (results, set) =>
        results flatMap { responses =>
          Future.sequence(runner(set)).map(responses ++=)
        }
      } map {
        _.result().sequenceU
      }
    }
  }
```

However, I can't get this to compile. I keep receiving the compiler error

```
value sequenceU is not a member of type parameter C[Either[play.api.mvc.Result,B]]
```

I've imported both `scalaz._` and `Scalaz._`, and I know they've provided a `Traverse[_]` for my use case (which is `List[_]` in this example). I'm pretty sure this is some sort of implicit resolution issue with the types, but I'm stumped on how to proceed forward resolving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this happens because Scalaz doesn't provide typeclass instances for `Seq` but instead for `IndexedSeq` and `List`. As such, you'll need to provide the `Traverse` instance yourself (note the additional implicit argument `C` to `batchRequests`):

```
final class BatchedList[A, C[X] <: Seq[X]](val targetList: C[A]) extends AnyVal {
  def batchRequests[B](batchSize: Int)(runner: Seq[A] => Seq[Future[Either[Result, B]]])
    (implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[C[A], Either[Result, B], C[Either[Result, B]]], C: Traverse[C]): Future[Either[Result, C[B]]] =
      targetList.grouped(batchSize).foldLeft(Future.successful(bf(targetList))) { (results, set) =>
        results flatMap { responses =>
          Future.sequence(runner(set)).map(responses ++=)
        }
      } map {
        _.result().sequenceU
      }
}
```

As you can see, this will return a sequence type corresponding to the type provided as `C`:

```
scala> def run[A](s: Seq[A]): Seq[Future[Either[Result, A]]] =
     |   s.map(i => Future.successful(Right(i)))
run: [A](s: Seq[A])Seq[scala.concurrent.Future[Either[Result,A]]]

scala> :t new BatchedList(List(1,2,3)).batchRequests(1)(run)
scala.concurrent.Future[Either[Result,List[Int]]]

scala> :t new BatchedList(Vector(1,2,3)).batchRequests(1)(run)
scala.concurrent.Future[Either[Result,scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int]]]
```

If you always want it to return a `Seq` it's a simple matter of an upcast.

Comment: But the result of `_.result()` is not a `Seq[_]`, but a `C[_]`, which when called on a List, should be `List[_]`

Comment: When called on a `List`, it does indeed return a `Future[Either[Result, List[B]]]` – isn't this what you asked for? I've edited my answer to illustrate this.

Comment: Got it, I missed the addition of the `implicit C: Traverse[C]`. So then I guess my question is, why is that additional parameter needed? Since I've imported all the implicits with `Scalaz._` in the same scope as the function declaration, why do I need to add it in the method signature? I guess I'm confused on the implicit resolution rules.

Comment: I'm not an expert on this stuff, but my understanding of the reason is that as you'd written it, you've told it that `targetList` is a `C[A]` where `C[_] <: Seq[_]`. Thus, even though the compiler knows that `C` is *some* child type of `Seq`, it doesn't know which one, and as there are no `Traverse` for `Seq` but only for *some* of its sub-types, there's no appropriate instance for it to find. For example, when `C` is `List`, there is indeed a `Traverse[List]` instance, but in this method Scala doesn't *know* `C` is `List`.